# Merge commit from main branch to release

Tags: git, github, git-squash

I have two main separate branch `Master` and `release`. My two PR(pull request) merged to Master branch called. `featureA` and `featureB` and deleted. Also many other feature branch merged to Master by different people.

Now, I want to create new PR/branch based on `release` branch called `releaseAB`, which should have commit from `featureA` and `featureB` as a single commit.

I tried.

```
git checkout release
git checkout -b releaseAB
git reflog **(Which doesn't show hash of `featureA` and `featureB` as it's on Develop branch)**
git cherry-pick <not sure which should I cherry pick)
```

I am not good in git So, not sure what should I do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The branches may have been deleted but the PR keeps the commits alive. So you can fetch the PR and its commits and cherry pick the ones you want, and squash them.

Comment: @matt Which cherry-pick hash I should use? I can not find any hash in reflog

Comment: I mean I cannot find hash related to featureA and featureB commit

Comment: No, it's not in your reflog. It's on the server. That's why I said fetch.

Comment: I checkout to Master and did `git fetch` but, not showing hash.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

Comment: Ahh got it. But, it does not stash changes locally. `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME` and what should I do if need changed from multiple PR?

Comment: As I said, treat that as a temporary branch, cherry pick any desired commits onto your real branch, and now manipulate the commits as desired.